# How to show notification after certain time in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an App which is based on certain notification by which user performs an action I want to show notification and after notification I want to add add Time + 5 minutes to show next notification. and also run Timer process in background when app is closed.

```
 public long Time = 3600;
 private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        Timer();

    }


    public void Timer() {

        for (long i = Time; i < 86400000; i = i += 60000) {

            new CountDownTimer(1000, i) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    ShowNotification();


                }
            }.start();
        }


    }

    public void ShowNotification() {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Example")
                .setContentText("Example Action")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try AlarmReceiver in that case.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

Comment: I should run this i for loop?

Comment: No, No need of loop. It will iterate automatically after 2 hr. You can change the time.

Comment: This code is not for showing notifications. This is for notifcation's property.

Comment: Go to this class. https://github.com/afreakyelf/newsapp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/student/newsapp/AlarmReceiver.java .......... Just look at it that how i modified notification. And call alarm manager inside main activity or wherever you want.